# Laravel 5 Eloquent - how to get scope columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scope, eloquent

I am trying to write a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes) and I need to know if any of the previous scopes added any **->select()** information earlier and if not, then add it (which would erase the previous stuff).

The scope gets a $query object which is \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder (according to the docs anyway)

If I look into Builder.php I see the $columns property which is used to store the columns to fetch

```
/**
 * The columns that should be returned.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $columns;
```

However in my scope if I try to access it using

```
$query->columns
```

I get an error message saying:

```
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$columns
```

As you can see there is some sort of magic going on behind and it is looking at Eloquent\Builder and not at Database\Query\Builder.

I am probably missing something simple here, maybe need more coffee again... Any pointers are welcome

Thanks

PS. I know I can use addSelect() but I would like to know why I am not able to access the 'columns' variable still...

Comment: This is Eloquent model you are accessing not Query Builder. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: No, it is not a model, a scope gets the query builder. See the eloquent manual. The page is linked to the question. Click on the scope which has the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object that gets passed to your **scope** method is of class **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder**, while the class that has the **columns** attribute is **Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder**. Object of the first class uses internally object of the second class so if you want to access its public properties you need to do:

```
public function scopeFunction($query) {
  $columns = $query->getQuery()->columns;
}
```

Keep in mind that some scopes can be applied after your scope is called and modify **$columns** attribute after your scope is run.

Comment: You are right. I actually solved this also myself yesterday but forgot to post it here. My IDE did not show getQuery() because of how Laravel uses magic calls. I had to go in find find it.

I just needed to find if the columns was empty or not. Because when Laravel builds the query string, if 'columns' is empty, it defaults to '*' but if not, then well uses what is in it. My scopes added some joins and select columns, so if $columns  is empty, I have to add some basic columns from first table to be shown. (or else only joined tables columns were shown)